# JSON parsing in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, json, swift

I've been trying to get image links from the json data in this Google API link in Xcode using swift:

> https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers

These are the keys:

```
import UIKit

struct Kind: Decodable {
    let kind: String
    let items: [Item]
}
struct Item: Decodable {
    let id: String
    let etag: String
    let volumeInfo: VolumeInfo
}
struct VolumeInfo: Decodable {
    let title: String
    let publisher: String
    let imageLinks: ImageLinks
}
struct ImageLinks: Decodable{
    let smallThumbnail: String
    let thumbnail: String
}
```

And this is the json parsing:

```
func fetchPictures(){
        let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers")
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url!) { (data, _, _) in
            guard let data = data else {return}
            do {
                let book = try JSONDecoder().decode(Kind.self, from: data)
                print(book.items)
            } catch {}
        }.resume()
    }
```

If i comment out the volumeInfo guy in the Item struct, i get the ids and etags in the console no problem. But if i leave volumeInfo and try to get to the image links through this nested data, it doesn't show anything in the console. I've been trying to do this all day and still can't figure out whats wrong.

Comment: `catch` and `print` the `error`. It tells you exactly what's wrong. Hint: `...Links` is plural

Comment: Thank you. That's smart. The thing was 'publisher' key wasn't in every dictionairy